# Anno2070 activation code cycle

Tags: steam, windows-8, anno-2070

I bought anno2070 two days ago on steam  but couldn't play  since. The game keeps asking me for  the activation code  which I enter and it accepts but than  it redirects me to the activation  window. I enter the  code  it accepts and  the cycle continues. Could it have anything to do with SSL?

I am also having trouble with Chrome not letting me login to any SSL sites without showing an error. Could this be related? I refreshed the PC (as they say in Windows 8) and uninstalled Chrome and the game several times. I have no viruses or malware on my laptop.

Any other ideas that could help? I Googled the problem but found nothing.

Comment: Could be a whole host of things. A couple of the basics to look at first are: Are you running as an admin? Is your firewall blocking the game/launchers/uPlays internet access?

Comment: Nope the firewall is letting all of this through and I am the administrator and am running the Programms as such.

I am also having trouble with chrome letting me not login to any ssl sites without showing an error. Could this be related? I refreshed the pc (as they say in windows 8) and Uninstaller chrome and the game several times. I have no viruses or malware on my laptop.

Any other ideas that could help? I Google the problem but found nothing.

Comment: It could possibly be SSL related, however since that would mean it's an issue with your computer/network rather than the game/game-services themselves, so would unfortunately take this question out of the reach of this site. I'd personally look into getting SSL connections to work in general, then retry this game.

Comment: Do you know where to look at the ssl  or what to look for? Or should I just another exchange site?